# CSS table text-align not working on some values in column

Tags: css, html-table, text-align

I have two columns, one of values for a variable and another of rankings of those values. The rankings column works fine; it is aligned left and 70% of the size of the values column. However, in the values column, all values in the column align right (as I want them to) except for the last value. The issue seems to be related to the number of characters in the value.

[Here are the two columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCcHr.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like the max-width or width is set too small to fit that many characters. not sure why you need to use %, try not setting any css for width, it should auto size.

Comment: Please provide a live copy of these tables in action so we can provide more assistance. If you don't have a live url you can share, stackoverflow allows you to provide code snippets with html+css+js (where needed) to create a simulation of your site for others to see

Answer (score 0):

It seems the last value is still aligning-right, but as you mentioned with the increased values in the left column it is pushing them together. If you are able, increasing the overall size of the column to account for increased values. (e.g. increase column padding and/or width).